# Invalid Foreign key on a trigger Opportunity quotes

Tags: trigger, soql

I am getting an error saying Save error:Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.quotes

```
List<Opportunity> oppsFromDb =  [SELECT
                                 id, stageName, name, accountid, owner__c, 
                                 end_user_contact__c, recordTypeId, ownerId,
                                 (SELECT id FROM Service_Contracts__r), 
                                 (SELECT id, Agreement_Term__c, Transcoding_Overage__c, Media_Storage_Overage__c,Data_Transfer_Overage__c,
                                  Equipment_Totals__c, Set_Up_Fee_Totals__c, Monthly_Recurring_Totals__c, Commencement_Date__c,
                                  Media_Object_Overage__c, Media_Request_Storage_Overage__c, Entitled_Media_Storage__c,
                                  Entitled_Data_Transfer__c, Entitled_Transcoding__c, Entitled_Media_Object__c, Entitled_Media_Reqest__c From quotes)
                                FROM
                                 Opportunity 
                                WHERE
                                 id IN:oppIds
                                ];
```

The call is to the quote is :

```
for(Opportunity goodOpps: oppsFromDb){      
  SContract.add(new ServiceContract(Quote__c = goodOpps.quotes.id, etc...));}
```

Do i need to create seperate lists for the quote and the Service Contract? Making it 3 seperate SOQL queries and then having to run separate queries to the lists when I need to get information specific to the parent opportunity?

Thanks

Comment: Side note.. In java ending a line without a ';' usually ends up in error, in SQL though it is ok and allows for neatness. Does Apex allow lines that do not end with ';' ( I imagine so since i'm not getting a million errors but just wanted to confirm)

Comment: Your first "line" (using that term loosely) in Apex would simply be that entire statement for your `List`. It will allow you to enter line breaks and continue your logic on the next line while considering it all a single statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accessing the `quotes` object properly there. The `quotes` object is actually a `List<Quote>`. You would need to do something like `goodOpps.quotes.get(0).id` to access that properly (assuming you want the first ID)

Comment: ahh, would I assume i should be able to add an additional WHERE CLAUSE for the quotes so.. SELECT ... FROM QUOTES WHERE iSynced == TRUE]; that way I make sure i only have a .quote.get(0).id as the correct quote

Comment: Yep, you can definitely do that if you know for sure that will only return the exact quote you want